# get application needed permissions

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-fql, user-permissions

What I am trying to do is get a list of permissions that an application will ask for when a user adds it.  FQL says I need an app access token (which of course requires the application secret).  I must be doing something wrong...I don't find it normal than only the developer of an application would be able to use the Graph to read the permissions the app requires.  Has anyone seen something similar?

Answer (score 0):

The permissions that you ask for depend on the script that is calling the login at that particular point, so it could be different in many places. One place in the app may only require basic permissions, while another place might require basic and email permissions. So you can't get a one-size-fits-all answer for an app because it isn't defined in one place, and it is not saved on the facebook server.

It might be that there is another solution to the reason why you want this information. What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Abby.  What I want is to be able to specify a random application and see what private information it can harvest if a user adds it to his profile.  Isn't this the "User & Friend Permissions" the developer sets in the FB Developer platform for his application?

Comment: No - that isn't possible. Its not part of the configuration of the app. Like I said, it could be different at any integration point depending what parameters the dev provides at that particular authorisation point. The idea behind this being that you only ask for extra permissions when they are needed. E.g. I don't need your email address until you try to opt into a newsletter. THEN I ask for extra permissions